# :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses' Error building a navigation drawer activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

I want to use the template of navigation drawer activity with Java in Android Studio, but when I build it throw the :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses' Error followed of a lot of lines saying that kotlin classes in module kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 are duplicated, but I'm using as language Java, not Kotlin, this is a part of the message:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
```

Note: This just happend with navigation drawer activity, empty activity and basic activity work fine and I've not added more to the default template.

A lot of places say that check the dependencies of the build.gradle and check if there are something duplicated, but I already checked it and I don't have anything duplicated

Please I need your help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue starting a brand new app using the navigation drawer activity. It was frustrating because a brand new project immediately broke To fix, just add an ignore at the bottom of the build.gradle(:app) file and re-sync

```
configurations.implementation {
    exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', module: 'kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
}
```